# Recipient details in HTML Email Template

Tags: email-template

I would like to enter recipient details (First Name and Last Name) in the HTML Email Template body. My recipients are always my Salesforce users and they are having always first name and last name.

I tried the below merge fields in the email template:

- {!Receiving_User.Name}
- {!Receiving_User.FirstName} {!Receiving_User.LastName}

Can someone please help me to understand what merge fields I should use to get the receiving user's details in the email template? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=merge_fields_email_templates.htm&language=en_US

As you can see in tips  section that

> The {!Receiving_User.field_name} and {!Sending_User.field_name} merge fields work only for mass email and are unavailable in Visualforce email templates.

For single email you know the user you are sending so while sending you can reference their name directly .

If you are sending to contact use Related to as Contact and if user select Related to as User .Once you select Related To object you can define merge fields and reference same in the Email template.

{!User.FirstName}

Comment: Hi Mohit, I want to send email to all the Sales VPs in my organization from approval final approval action. How can I refer individual Sales VPs first name and last name in the email template?